# Chrome Browser consuming CPU in Lununtu

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, cpu

I have been running Lubuntu on one computer for a few years. Performance has really degraded over the last few months and when I run the qps monitor, I see chrome consuming most of the CPU. When idle the usage does go down. See attached screen print. I ran memtest 86 plus and it passed. How can I diagnose? Could updates to Chrome and Lubuntu require more computer power so this system is getting obsolete? Falkon does run slightly better but it less desirable.  Could another flavor of Linux help?  From what I can see, memory is not an issue.

Lubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Gateway NE71B
AMD Dual-Core Processor, 1400 MHz
8 GB Memory

Google Chrome
Version 121.0.6167.184 (Official Build) (64-bit)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Chrome is famous for consuming resources. Try Firefox, or if you're willing to go to the extreme, Lynx

Comment: Try Brave browser. It too is built on chromium, It runs okay on an old machine (1.8 mhz). I get 1-2 % cpu usage when idle. No browser should consume a lot when minimized.